# Artifactory build info url is incorrect

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a simple job which uploads an artifact and publishes Build info

on Jenkins URL for Build info is
`https://artifacts.******.com/**artifactory**/ui/builds/project_name/73/1626838876890/published`

but this link should be
`https://artifacts.******.com/ui/builds/project_name/73/1626838876890/published`

Without `artifactory`

What is the issue?

Here is pipeline code:

```
stage ('Upload Artifactory') {
        steps {
            script { 
                echo "Starting to upload Artifact"                
                rtUpload (
                   "serverId": "Artifact_server",
                   "buildName": JOB_NAME,
                   "buildNumber": BUILD_NUMBER,
                   "spec": """{
                        "files": [{
                            "pattern": "*.zip",
                            "target": "generic/myfolder/"
                        }]
                    }"""
                )
            }
        }
    }
    stage ('Publish build info') {
        steps {
            rtPublishBuildInfo (
                "serverId": "Artifact_server",
                "buildName": JOB_NAME,
                "buildNumber": BUILD_NUMBER
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your Jenkins Artifactory plugin version?

Comment: Antifactory Plugin Version: 3.12.4

Answer (score 3):

The build-info URL has changed since Artifactory 7. To better support this change in Jenkins Artifactory plugin, an option was added in 3.12.1 to configure the JFrog platform URL in the global configuration.

To make it work, Browse to `Manage Jenkins | Configure System | JFrog` and set your JFrog platform URL:
[image: JFrog instance details]